# How do I write a simple Servlet for Jetty using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jetty, war

I downloaded Eclipse for Java EE and Jetty 8.1 and would like to implement a very simple Servlet.

Jetty works fine when I start it using `java -jar start.jar`.

To develop the Servlet I did this:

1. In Eclipse, I choosed "New Dynamic Web Project".
2. I added `jetty\lib\servlet-api-3.0.jar` to the "Build Path" in Eclipse.
3. In that project, "New Servlet", and a Servlet was generated and I added some code:

   ```
   /**
    * Servlet implementation class MyServlet
    */
   @WebServlet("/MyServlet")
   public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       /**
        * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
        */
       protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.println("<html><body><h1>My Servlet</h1></body></html>");
       }

       /**
        * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
        */
       protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }

   }
   ```
4. I created a file `web.xml` in `WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml` with this content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4">
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>MyServlet.class</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>My Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
5. I copied the compiled `.class`-files in `build\classes` to `WebContent\WEB-INF\classes`
6. Now I choose to Export the project as a `.war`-file to `jetty\webapps\MySite.war`.
7. I start Jetty with `java -jar start.jar` and visit `localhost:8080/MySite/Servlet` but now I get this message:

   ```
   Servlet Not Initialized

   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet Not Initialized
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:546)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:485)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:483)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:412)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:451)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:916)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:233)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:615)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
   ```

and if I visit `localhost:8080/MySite/` I see two folders `WEB-INF\` and `META-INF\` both with size `0 bytes`.

So it doesn't look like my `.war`-export in Eclipse worked.

How do I export my simple Servlet for Jetty using Eclipse?

---

I have now installed the [Jetty WTP plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty_WTP_Plugin) for Eclipse, but I can't run this servlet using it:

```
2012-01-30 10:06:50.322:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.0.RC4
2012-01-30 10:06:50.353:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Users\Jonas\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps at interval 1
2012-01-30 10:06:50.353:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Users\Jonas\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\contexts at interval 1
2012-01-30 10:06:50.353:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\Users\Jonas\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\contexts\MySite.xml
2012-01-30 10:06:50.650:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/MySite,file:/C:/Users/Jonas/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MySite/},C:\Users\Jonas\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/wtpwebapps/MySite: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1214)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.createAnnotationParser(AnnotationConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1214)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:82)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your web.xml is wrong.

> The servlet-class element contains the fully qualified class name of the servlet.

from web.xml schema you used http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd at line 923. Hence, the content of servlet-class element at line 9 should be `MyServlet`, not `MyServlet.class`.

Second, use only one way to register a servlet, filter or listener to make it clear. If you prefer to use annotation to register them to a servlet container. You had better delete servlet and servlet-mapping element in web.xml. Otherwise, You had better delete annotations in java source. And if you want to use web.xml, you should update the schema version from 2.4 to 3.0

Finally, your second problem came from the Jetty WTP Eclipse plugin can be solved by trying this: [jetty run error for websockets project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054303/jetty-run-error-for-websockets-project/9055691#9055691)

Comment: I changed the servlet-class element from `MyServlet.class` to `my.package.MyServlet` and commented out the `@WebServlet`-annotation and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are accessing the servet may be wrong.
If we observe the war you are deploying is `MySite.war`
and the url you are using is `localhost:8080\MyServlet\Servlet`

Try with `localhost:8080\MySite\Servlet`

Comment: Also you can add a plugin in eclipse to connect to you Jetty server via eclipse itself. Try adding new server. and then you can run your application directly within eclipse no need to export to war and then publish to Jetty seperately

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo by me, I was visiting `localhost:8080\MySite\Servlet`. The URI ``localhost:8080\MyServlet\Servlet` returns `404 Not Found`. I will have a look for the plugin, but it should work to export a war-file too.